# Calculate absolute value using matrix

Tags: matrices, absolute-value

Let's say I have a vector `a`.
I would like to construct a matrix or vector `b` such that if I multiply `a` and `b`, I get the absolute value of `a`.

In other words I would like to calculate the absolute value of a vector by multiplying it with a matrix or a vector.

Is such a matrix/vector possible to construct, assuming that I do not know anything about `a`?

I would like to do this without using `a`.

Comment: To get the absolute value in squared form, you can multiply the vector with its transpose. think of 1by2 times 2by1 gives 1by1 So $<a,b>*<a,b>^T$ = $a^2+b^2$ but then you would have to take the √ manually. In a lot of situations, working with the squared form is easier, hence my primitive idea

Comment: but I only need the absolute value of a. So I want to a*b=abs(a)

Comment: hmmm, I understand now what you mean. That's tough I think. I wouldn't know at this point. I hope maybe somebody smarter could give you some clue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question of if there is a single $b$ which works for any vector $a$ where $b$ does not depend on $a$, first note that projections are self-adjoint operators, that is $\Pi = \Pi^*$.

Define $\Pi_a$ to be the projection onto the subspace generated by the vector $a$.

$|a| = \langle a, b\rangle = \langle \Pi_a a, b\rangle = \langle a, \Pi_a b\rangle$

also, $\langle a, b\rangle = |a||b|\cos \theta\leq |a|$

These together implies that $\Pi_a b = b$, which is to say that $b\in \text{span}\{a\}$

Take some vector $c$ such that $c\perp a$ and $|c|\neq 0$

Then $\langle c, b \rangle = \langle c, \Pi_a b\rangle = \langle \Pi_a c, b\rangle = \langle 0, b\rangle = 0 \neq |c|$

This shows that there cannot exist a $b$ in any space that includes perpendicular vectors, but still could exist in 1-deminsional space.  For one-dimensional space, the number $1$ does the trick if only using positive numbers, but including negative numbers will ruin that as well.

---

tldr: $b$ will *always* depend on what $a$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $a\ne 0$ and take $b=\frac{a}{|a|}.$ Then $$a\cdot b=\frac{a\cdot a}{|a|}=|a|.$$

Comment: thank you for your answer. I was not clear in my original question. I would like to do this without using 'a'. Is that possible?